# Check if discord role is above another role

Tags: javascript, node.js, roles, discord.js

I'm having trouble with one of my bots, I want to check if the bot role above other roles, I tried

```
message.guild.roles.array()
```

and yeah, it did work. However, it wasn't in the correct order and I couldn't check if the role was above another. Can anyone tell me how to check if the bot role is above other roles? Thanks.

Comment: According to the documentation, it sounds like it returns a list of `role` objects, which each have a `position` property. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes, it is the case, and I know now how I can use it to check positions, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out I didn't want to go through all the roles, so I just checked the positions of the 2 roles I am comparing

```
let role = message.mentions.roles.first();
let botrole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Mobile Friendly")
if(role.position > botrole.position){
    return await message.channel.send("I can't access that role, place me above other roles that you want me to manage.")
}
```